# saving favourite tracks from radio stream

Tags: linux, ubuntu, streaming, pipe, dbus

**Here is the general description of my problem.**

I have folder for my favourite music (ok, that's not actually a problem :D) There are 2-3 radio station streams which I periodically switch between. Sometimes when I listen to some track on radio I realize that I like it and want to save it to my folder of favourites. As you may guess the problem is that when I decide I want track to be saved it has been already played partially, while it should be saved entirely from the start.

So in general it should be like this: I'm listening to stream -> decide I want it to save to my folder -> press some button -> after the track on radio stream is finished it appears in my favourites folder.

I use ubuntu linux 10.04, rhythmbox for stream listening. I'm ok with installing any other programs either from ubuntu repository or from external source. I'm ok with writing/using python, bash scripts or even programs in java or c++.

**My research on this problem follows.**

Popular software for radio stream ripping is streamripper. I had no problem with it, saving all tracks to a single file or splitting incoming stream into separate files.
So my first approach was just to start ripping stream into separate tracks and relay it to be able to listen myself.
Problems with this approach:

- I end up with lots of files, which I'll then have to process,
  removing all of them but the ones I liked
- How do I remember which tracks I actually liked?
- Hard disk load - when ripping from 2-3 stream it seems to become a constant load on disk. This seems overkill as most of the data saved to disk will then be deleted

I believe the first problem can be solved with some sort of background program/script - deleting latest file if "I like" button hasn't been pressed before.

The second problem can be solved using dbus for rhythmbox, for example by writing [python script](http://blog.mafr.de/2006/12/10/controlling-rhythmbox-using-dbus/) to ask rhythmbox the name of the currently playing track.

I haven't come up yet with the solution for third problem. It seems to me that linux named pipes is the way to avoid any disk load at all. But when ripping to separate tracks streamripper does the creation of files so I can't make them named pipes instead of regular files. Of course I can create named pipe and instruct stramripper to save the entire stream to this file, while reading data from the other end of pipe with some program. But in this case I can't use track splitting logic of streamripper.

So how do I solve my problem? Is there any way I can complete my approach by solving third problem? Or is there a completely different approach to my general problem? The only software requirement is ubuntu itself. I can accept any programs.

Comment: why not rip to a ram disk and then move the file when you mark it with "i like" button?

Comment: @F.C. I'm not familiar with ram disk at all. Does working with it produces absolutely no load at hard disk? Can I mount and unmount it without modifying my system configuration? Anyway this seems promising. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ram disk would not touch the hard disk, but you should have enough ram to save your ripped content.

https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+make+ram+disk

Comment: I've found that on my installation there is already ramdisk ready to use - /dev/shm. I can't see any problems with implementing my idea now, thank you!